# Why is iframe a pair tag

Tags: html

Why is iframe a pair tag if you can't define it's content like this:

```
<iframe>
Text content
</iframe>
```

Why it isn't unpaired tag just like img?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because content between iframe pair tags should be displayed when iframe isn't supported.

> The contents of the IFRAME element, on the other hand, should only be
>   displayed by user agents that do not support frames or are configured
>   not to display frames. [(HTML 4.0 frames)](https://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-html40-19980424/present/frames.html#h-16.5)

Example:

```
 <IFRAME src="foo.html" width="400" height="500" scrolling="auto" frameborder="1">
  [Your user agent does not support frames or is currently configured
  not to display frames. However, you may visit
  <A href="foo.html">the related document.</A>]
  </IFRAME>
```

Another good thing about paired iframes is that, browsers can simply display it's content in developer tools

Answer (score 0):

It is because the `iframe` element is not a self-closing element and the behavior is by design.

You can also check [this](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-validator/2010Sep/0017.html)

> The message would be clearer if instead of "a non-void HTML element"
>   it said  "an HTML element that is not defined-empty" or possibly "an
>   HTML element that is allowed to have content".
>
> Of course, this is correct for the present draft of html5 where "/>"
>   is only allowed for elements that are defined-empty in the vocabulary
>   of the html namespace.
>
> However, even though html5 is independent of sgml, I make this point
>   because sgml rules (with www mods) about NETENABL in relation to
>   "empty" elements address the syntactic issue -- whether the element
>   has de facto content -- rather than the vocabulary issue of whether
>   the element is defined-empty.

So there are other tags as well which are not designed to have a self closing tag as well. You can check it using the [W3C's validator](http://validator.w3.org/)